# boost::to_lower_copy() too expensive as it extracts a facet from the passed locale

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

I've got `std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>` showing up in a profiler. It is called indirectly from `boost::to_lower_copy()`.
I remember fixing this for a comparison operator by storing the reference returned from `std::use_facet<>` only once and repeatedly calling `facet.tolower(char)` with it, avoiding repeated calls to `std::use_facet<>`.
Is there a way to avoid this short of writing one's own `to_lower(const std::string&)` function?

Comment: File a bug against boost.

Comment: Side note: case conversion in general is not simple, sometimes you have one-to-many mapping and sometimes you cannot have a correct mapping without consulting a dictionary. Perhaps you need case folding rather than case conversion?

Comment: +1 for "I've got it showing up in a profiler". I wonder whether the use-case can be improved, but at least you proved that you have a problem with the current usage pattern. (Assuming it is significant relevant to say, the copying of the string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `use_facet<std::ctype<char>>` object instance is created inside `std::tolower()` which is internally called per character by `boost::to_lower_copy()`.
If your compiler doesn't optimize that out, even when all possible optimizations are enabled, I'm afraid you have no way to get around it. Boost does not provide any way to customize this function. Your only solution is to implement it yourself.

Here is one possible solution for `std::string` (contrary to boost's implementation which is generalized for arbitrary sequence type):

```
std::string to_lower_copy(const std::string& input,
    const std::locale& loc = std::locale())
{
    auto const& facet = std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(loc);

    std::string out;
    out.reserve(input.size());

    std::transform(input.begin(), input.end(), std::back_inserter(out),
        [&facet](unsigned char c) { return facet.tolower(c); });

    return out;
}
```

Here is a small [benchmark](https://godbolt.org/z/5bd9r9ThP) demonstrating ~5-7x performance advantage over boost:

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Benchmark           Time             CPU   Iterations
-----------------------------------------------------
BM_boost         4672 ns         2429 ns       443106
BM_our            697 ns          311 ns      2585506
```

Please mind that this approach is locale specific and doesn't work for arbitrary UTF-8 strings (same as boost).